# Django _unaccent and _search in Admin

Tags: python, django, search, django-admin

So I have found a way to use `_unaccent` and `_search` together in Django filters, but I'm trying to find a way to properly implement it into the search bar in the admin pages. So far I have the following code, but since I haven't done it properly, admin settings such as `search_fields = []` are not applying properly. I would appreciate it if someone could help me merge my solution with the original Django implementation.

`admin.ModelAdmin` function being overwritten:

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
    """
    Returns a tuple containing a queryset to implement the search,
    and a boolean indicating if the results may contain duplicates.
    """
    # Apply keyword searches.
    def construct_search(field_name):
        if field_name.startswith('^'):
            return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
        elif field_name.startswith('='):
            return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
        elif field_name.startswith('@'):
            return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
        else:
            return "%s__icontains" % field_name

    use_distinct = False
    search_fields = self.get_search_fields(request)
    if search_fields and search_term:
        orm_lookups = [construct_search(str(search_field))
                       for search_field in search_fields]
        for bit in search_term.split():
            or_queries = [models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                          for orm_lookup in orm_lookups]
            queryset = queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
        if not use_distinct:
            for search_spec in orm_lookups:
                if lookup_needs_distinct(self.opts, search_spec):
                    use_distinct = True
                    break

    return queryset, use_distinct
```

My code:

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):  # TODO: Make this more professionally implemented (proper overrides)
    """ Overrides default search completely to incorporate __search and __unaccent lookups """
    use_distinct = False

    if search_term:  # Note: "if" condition necessary to show ALL results in admin if not search_term is specified (otherwise shows 0 results)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(unaccent_title=SearchVector('title', config='english_unaccent')).filter(unaccent_title=SearchQuery(search_term, config='english_unaccent'))

    return queryset, use_distinct
```

> Django: 1.11.5
>
> Python: 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that, you want both search_fields and _unaccent search to work together.

I am not sure whether I understood your query properly or not.

Here is the solution for what I understood:

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):  # TODO: Make this more professionally implemented (proper overrides)
    """ Overrides default search completely to incorporate __search and __unaccent lookups """
    queryset1, use_distinct = super(<Admin class>, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)

    queryset2 = queryset
    if search_term:  # Note: "if" condition necessary to show ALL results in admin if not search_term is specified (otherwise shows 0 results)
        queryset2 = queryset.annotate(unaccent_title=SearchVector(*self.search_fields, config='english_unaccent')).filter(unaccent_title=SearchQuery(search_term, config='english_unaccent'))

    return queryset1 | queryset2, use_distinct
```

Let me know, if you wanted something else.